# Shopify Liquid attributes inside select tag

Tags: shopify

I want to ask that what are the following 2 attributes in side select tag. I searched them in theme.js file but they are not present there ?

**data-product-select**

**data-free-shipping=true**

```
      <select name="id" class="no-js" data-product-select data-free-shipping=true >
        {% for variant in product.variants %} 
        <option
            {% if variant == current_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
            {% unless variant.available %}disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}
            value="{{ variant.id }}" data-variant-name="{{ variant.title }}" data-variant-image="{{ variant.image.src | img_url }}"
            data-sale={% if variant.compare_at_price > variant.price %}true {% else %}false{% endif %}
            {% if thirty_days_after_publication > todays_date %}data-new-product=true{% endif %}>
              {{ variant.title }}
          </option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Comment: Are you sure this HTML and liquid code is the default theme code, might be added using any 3rd party APP?

Comment: It could be. Suppose if its 3rd party. Than what are these type of attributes and what they are doing!

Comment: Might be any APP JS code read these attributes to implement the logic related to their APP